# Requestcode and Resultcode handling for different modules

Tags: android, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

In my android app I have 'imageselect' module to choose image from gallery or camera captured image and 'app' module to process and show it. for different request code i did

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO = 2000;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 2006;
```

am getting request code and result code perfectly in imageselect module activity

start activity Result for both option

```
//to choose gallery image 
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageSelectActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_ALBUM, albums.get(position).name);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO); 


// to capture camera image     
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

OnActivity result:

```
if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(AlbumSelectActivity.this,"Calling ALbum IF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(AlbumSelectActivity.this,"Calling ALbum ELSE IF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Till this its working fine. In my app module activity always getting same requestcode. always getting 2000 which is photo requestcode.

App module MainActivity onActivityResult:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO && data != null) {
           // always getting 'REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO' so this block is working 

        } else if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && data != null) {
            // this block never called even when 'REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA' passed 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **App module MainActivity onActivityResult**:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO && data != null) {
           // always getting 'REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO' so this block is working 

        } else if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && data != null) {
            // this block never called even when 'REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA' passed 
        }else{}
    }
```

And for **OnActivity result**:

```
if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(AlbumSelectActivity.this,"Calling ALbum IF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(AlbumSelectActivity.this,"Calling ALbum ELSE IF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{}
```

Comment: you can't put condition in else so how it will even work ? Otherwise am always getting same requestcode thats the problem